# Get dependent ids when querying principal

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get just the ids for dependents if a principal is queried, every time the principal is queried.

My initial thought is to add it somehow in the OnModelCreating definitions, however that appears to be limited to filtering down larger sets of data, unless I'm missing something.

Something like this:

```
    builder.Entity<ListingModel>()
        .AlsoDoThis(
            x => x.MenuIds.AddRange(
                Menus.Where(y => y.ListingId == x.Id).Select(y => y.Id).ToList()
            )
        );
```

There is a need to *not* do this in code for each individual place I have a `Select`, since that functionality is normalized in [some base classes](https://github.com/freer4/ef-vue-mantle/blob/main/BaseClasses/ServiceBase.cs). The base classes have a `<TModel>` passed in and don't inherently know what properties need to be handled this way.

---

I *do* have a workaround where I'm grabbing everything with an `AutoInclude()`, then filtering it out in the model definition with customer getter/setter to return a list of ids. But rather than being more performant (grabbing related FK ids at the DB level) it's transferring all of that data to the server and then programmatically selecting a list of ids, as far as I understand it.

```
private List<int> _topicsIds = new();
[NotMapped]
public List<int> TopicsIds
{
    get { return Topics.Count > 0 ? Topics.Select(x => x.Id).ToList() : _topicsIds; }
    set { _topicsIds = value; }
}
public List<TopicModel> Topics { get; set; } = new();
```

---

"Extra SQL that gets called with every select in a context" is (to my limited knowledge) *almost* what `HasQueryFilter` does, with a just slightly broader operation. I think this is the approach I'm looking for, just *selecting more stuff* instead of *filtering stuff out*.

Comment: You can do that with custom projection via `Select`.  Includes are not needed in this case.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv do you have an example or the doc you can point to? I'm not following your thought here but I'm somewhat novice with EFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can project everything via `Select`

```cs
var result = ctx.ListingModels
   .Select(lm => new // or to DTO
   {
       Id = lm.Id,
       OtherProperty = lm.OtherProperty,
       
       Ids = x.MenuIds.Select(m => m.Id).ToList()
   })
   .ToList();
```

To make more general solution we can use annotations and define how to project such entities.

During Model defining:

```cs
builder.Entity<TopicModel>()
    .WithProjection(
        x => x.MenuIds,
        x => x.Menus.Where(y => y.ListingId == x.Id).Select(y => y.Id).ToList()
    );
```

Then usage in common code:

```cs
public virtual List<TModel> GetList(List<int> ids)
{
    var list = _context.Set<TModel>().Where(x => ids.Any(id => id == x.Id))
        .ApplyCustomProjection(_context)
        .ToList();
    return list;
}
```

`ApplyCustomProjection(_context)` will find previously defined annotation and will apply custom projection.

---

And extensions implementation:

```cs
public static class ProjectionExtensions
{
    public const string CustomProjectionAnnotation = "custom:member_projection";

    public class ProjectionInfo
    {
        public ProjectionInfo(MemberInfo member, LambdaExpression expression)
        {
            Member = member;
            Expression = expression;
        }

        public MemberInfo Member { get; }
        public LambdaExpression Expression { get; }
    }

    public static bool IsUnderDotnetTool { get; } 
        = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "dotnet";

    public static EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> WithProjection<TEntity, TValue>(
        this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> entity, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> propExpression, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> assignmentExpression) 
        where TEntity : class
    {
        // avoid registering non serializable annotations during migrations update
        if (IsUnderDotnetTool)
           return entity;

        var annotation = entity.Metadata.FindAnnotation(CustomProjectionAnnotation);
        var projections = annotation?.Value as List<ProjectionInfo> ?? new List<ProjectionInfo>();

        if (propExpression.Body is not MemberExpression memberExpression)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{propExpression.Body}' is not member expression");

        if (memberExpression.Expression is not ParameterExpression)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{memberExpression.Expression}' is not parameter expression. Only single nesting is allowed");

        // removing duplicate
        projections.RemoveAll(p => p.Member == memberExpression.Member);

        projections.Add(new ProjectionInfo(memberExpression.Member, assignmentExpression));
        return entity.HasAnnotation(CustomProjectionAnnotation, projections);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyCustomProjection<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, DbContext context)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var et = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
        var projections = et?.FindAnnotation(CustomProjectionAnnotation)?.Value as List<ProjectionInfo>;

        // nothing to do
        if (projections == null || et == null)
            return query;

        var propertiesForProjection = et.GetProperties().Where(p =>
            p.PropertyInfo != null && projections.All(pr => pr.Member != p.PropertyInfo))
            .ToList();

        var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");

        var memberBinding = new MemberBinding[propertiesForProjection.Count + projections.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < propertiesForProjection.Count; i++)
        {
            var propertyInfo = propertiesForProjection[i].PropertyInfo!;
            memberBinding[i] = Expression.Bind(propertyInfo, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(entityParam, propertyInfo));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < projections.Count; i++)
        {
            var projection = projections[i];
            var expression = projection.Expression.Body;

            var assignExpression = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(projection.Expression.Parameters[0], entityParam, expression);

            memberBinding[propertiesForProjection.Count + i] = Expression.Bind(projection.Member, assignExpression);
        }

        var memberInit = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(TEntity)), memberBinding);

        var selectLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TEntity>>(memberInit, entityParam);

        var newQuery = query.Select(selectLambda);
        return newQuery;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh okay. This makes sense, but I'm trying to do this on a more universal level (automatically return the dependent IDs rather than manually selecting them each time I use the principal)

Comment: It is right way. You need such query only for one controller, why you have to specify something in Model?

Comment: The larger scope is more complex. I have a dynamic base service and controller classes that lock in some standard functionality for interaction with many models. Listing out every property in a select for each child class basically negates the purpose

Comment: Then build Expression Tree dynamically, nothing special.

Comment: Could I get you to add an example of dynamic expression tree knowing only the TModel?  Nobody else seems to be offering any solutions, but my attempts at building a dynamic expression tree have all failed

Comment: @RandyHall, updated question with implementation of such dynamic projection.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is exactly what I want, but I am getting this trying to generate migration files now: 


Cannot scaffold C# literals of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EfVueMantle.Helpers.ProjectionExtensions+ProjectionInfo]'. The provider should implement CoreTypeMapping.GenerateCodeLiteral to support using it at design time.