# EF migration error about 'GenerateCodeLiteral' where application is working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I added some functionality to my entity definitions [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73491471/1750282). It works perfectly when I run the application. However, it throws an error when adding an EF migration:

> Cannot scaffold C# literals of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EfVueMantle.Helpers.ProjectionExtensions+ProjectionInfo]'. The provider should implement CoreTypeMapping.GenerateCodeLiteral to support using it at design time.

I really do not know what this means, and what very little I could find on "Generate Code Literal" didn't seem to relate to what I'm doing or offer much insight into the issue. That error makes it sound really simple, but I'm just blank.

If I comment out the uses of the code in question (shown below), the migration works, and then I can uncomment and run the application again. *This is not ideal*, obv.

```
builder.Entity<TopicModel>()
    .WithProjection(
        x => x.MenuIds,
        x => x.Menus.Select(y => y.Id).ToList()
    );
```

Comment: Where is the code you posted located? Inside the migration itself or in the Db context?

Comment: @Nannanas inside the db context, in OnModelCreating

Comment: Which EF Core provider do you use?

Comment: @ErikEJ SqlServer

Comment: What kind of data you shared with projection. It has issue with `.ToList()` that cause the migration as it is not supported by DB.

Comment: @KiranJoshi Basically, this is taking a linked entity `Menus` and projecting its `Id`s to the `MenuIds` property. The SQL is something like `SELECT MenuId FROM TopicMenus WHERE TopicId = {x}`, probably a join in there but you get the gist

Comment: Can you do not execute `WithProjection` if there is scaffolding? If you can separated this part it will be best solution. Excluding also can be included in `WithProjection` method.

Comment: It can be simple check in which process library code is executed.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv if you can show it in an answer you can get the bounty

Comment: How do you execute migrations?

Comment: Powershell command line `dotnet ef` stuff usually, but I could use VS console also. PS is just faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect that your configuration is executed under `dotnet` tool and do not register annotations which cannot be used with migrations.

Simple extension method:

```
public static class ProjectionExtensions
{
    ... // code from original answer

    public static bool IsUnderDotnetTool { get; } 
        = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "dotnet";
 
    public static EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> WithProjection<TEntity, TValue>(
        this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> entity, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> propExpression, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> assignmentExpression) 
        where TEntity : class
    {
        // avoid registering non serializable annotations
        if (IsUnderDotnetTool)
           return entity;

        ... // rest code from original answer
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful thanks! Credited you in my [source files](https://github.com/freer4/ef-vue-mantle/blob/main/Helpers/ProjectionExtensions.cs) (that it's admittedly unlikely anyone else will ever see lol). Your help has overcome a *massive* performance issue that's bugged me for a while now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77801054/projection-not-applied-but-only-in-certain-environments?noredirect=1#comment137156735_77801054 lead me back here, small world. So it seems the process name is dotnet when building in our the pipeline. Is there an alternative check that both doesn't break this solution, and fixes the pipeline-built app problem from the linked question?

Comment: Define additional static variable in `ProjectionExtensions` `prublic static bool IsApplicationMode = false`. For example when starting a Web API,  set this variable  `ProjectionExtensions.IsApplicationMode = true`. Change detection code `if (!IsApplicationMode )
           return entity;`

Comment: Good idea. Also came up with `Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName == "dotnet-ef").Any()` do you see any caveats to this approach?

Comment: Bad idea, concurrent run may fail. Run in parallel `dotnet ef` and your application.