# Create Simple join in Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do the simple, something I've done countless times in SQL, but I have Table A, it has a id column as the primary key - which I'm not using here.  Table B also has one, also not used for this.

I want to get all the rows in B, that match on a column that is in A (int) and have them show up in that entity.

Thus: Let's for sake of argument say that both tables have a column called "Joiner", If I was writing this in SQL, I'd say:

```
Select A.*, B.* from TableA A  
Join TableB B on A.Joiner = B.Joiner
```

Easy right? Couldn't be a more common thing unless it was A.Id... But it isn't

So, in Entity Frameworks Core, I want to get an A by id, .Include B.

Now, I get A.Bs  which is a list of all the B's that match the A's on their Joiner fields.

Super Easy right?

I'm using the `EntityMappingConfiguration<A>` and `EntityMappingConfiguration<B>` to define the mapping, Overriding the 'Map()' Method, so things that tell me how to modify that would be most helpful.

I've been able to have it create mappings that are looking for B.Joiner = A.Id, And things that are looking for an array of B to exist in A (that just doesn't even make sense)...

Oh, there are MANY B's that match A's value, and could be that same value in many other A's (From what I can tell it is a Many to Many relationship, except that you would never ask for B's matching A records.)   The idea being that we can update A's Joiner value, and have it switch to a different B, and thus, be able to pick up other configuration columns in B..

Just seems like this should be a slam dunk, yet, none of the Entity Framework (core) guru's seem to be able to do this.

In reference to code examples, I have about 200 things that don't work. Here is one example:

```
public class TableAMap: EntityMappingConfiguration<TableA>
{
    public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<TableA> b)
    {
        b.ToTable("TableA");
        b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        b.Property(x => x.Id).UseIdentityColumn();

        b.HasMany(x => x.TableBs)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Joiner);
     }
 }
```

The class TableA has a Joiner field that is an Int and a Joiners field that is public virtual ICollection Joiners{ get; set; }, (In my case, I'm calling TableB the same as the field, so both would be 'Joiner' in this case.)   But it wants to use the Id/TableAId to join.   I've tried using HasPrincipalKey () - which seems like exactly what I'm wanting to do, except that there is a comment on the documentation that says "if there is not a unique constraint, it will add one" - sigh, there are multiple duplicate values, so nope, not unique, so please don't automatically add the constraint!

I'll try to write up an example that is simple (and isn't code that I can't share)

Comment: Any code/Model examples? I really do not understand difficulty of your problem and where do you stuck.

Comment: the issue is that I am NOT using the primary keys, so how do I tell it that Joiner is the column that is the same in both tables?   I'm having it "Automatically" Use TableA.Id as the Foreign Key going to a (nonexistent) column of TableAId in TableB.

Comment: Show in code how do you plan to use `Joiner`.

Comment: Note that `Include` is not `join` it is instruction to load related entity. If you need such functionality for easy querying it can be done differently. Changing Entity configuration can be really bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I put in the comment about the Include to indicate that I would need to do that in the query to get it to add these Entities.   So far, the only solution that I've come up with is to use the HasPrincipalKey(), which adds the Unique Constraint and then delete it from the resulting migration - which sounds like a bad idea...   (No clue why it would think that it would be Unique in TableA just because you are using it to query Table B for all the rows that match there)

Comment: I can't for the life of me understand why the Unique Constraint is added - Just because you are using a column in table 1 to query into table 2, doesn't mean that that value is unique in table 1.. Except, that it seems like it does in EF..

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73907971/10646316) it has property `IsUnderDotnetTool`, check this property and do not apply `HasPrincipalKey` during migration generation.  For EF Core 7, there is possibility to disable generating indexes.