# EF Core ignore OwnsMany property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using `IEntityTypeConfiguration` to configure my models with EF Core 6, and one of the property is declared as a relation by using the `OwnsMany` method.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Distributor>().OwnsMany(
p => p.ShippingCenters, a =>
{
    a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("OwnerId");
    a.Property<int>("Id");
    a.HasKey("Id");
});
```

My question: is there a way to remove property from my model that is configured with `OwnsMany`, but ignore it in migration? I can do it with normal property using [Ignore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.ignore?view=efcore-2.1) method. But after I've removed the property and used `Ignore` method like this:

```
modelBuilder.Ignore("ShippingCenters");
```

The next migration is going to remove the `ShippingCenters` table. It's important to me to keep this table in the database.

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: You could create an inherited class with property ShippingCenters and make migration use base class.

Comment: Hi, but I want to remove ShippingCenters from model and keep the table in database

Comment: How about detecting that code currently used by `dotnet` tool (Migration genrration) and do not execute code which add `OwnsMany`? I have created example [here (IsUnderDotnetTool)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73907971/10646316)

Comment: You can always manually edit the generated migration and remove code deleting/restoring the table.