# Projection not applied but only in certain environments

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We have a relatively simple projection that is working for local development environment, but when deployed this projection appears to be ignored. No errors are logged.

I'm looking less for a definitive answer (though I will take one if someone knows) and more interested in what could possibly be causing such an inconsistency.

The application is building locally and in the deployment pipeline using the latest from dotnet 6.x. Both use EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.10.

```
builder.Entity<UserAccountModel>()
    .WithProjection(x => x.CustomerAccountsIds, x => x.CustomerAccounts.Select(y => y.Id).ToList())
    .WithProjection(x => x.UserPermissionsIds, x => x.UserPermissions.Select(y => y.Id).ToList());
```

The projection is there to give us a list of ids from the associated models. Again, this works as expected when running locally via VS.

Local environment logs this, notice the LEFT JOINs:

```
SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[ContactEmail], [s].[ContactPhoneNumber], [s].[Created], [s].[DeletedAt], [s].[FirstActive], [s].[FirstName], [s].[InternalUser], [s].[IsDeleted], [s].[LastActive], [s].[LastName], [s].[LockId], [s].[SelectedCustomerAccounts], [s].[Title], [s].[Updated], [s].[UserRoleId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[CustomerAccountsId], [t0].[UserAccountsId], [u].[Id]
FROM [UserAccounts] AS [s]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t].[Id], [c].[CustomerAccountsId], [c].[UserAccountsId]
    FROM [CustomerAccountModelUserAccountModel] AS [c]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [c0].[Id]
        FROM [CustomerAccounts] AS [c0]
    ) AS [t] ON [c].[CustomerAccountsId] = [t].[Id]
) AS [t0] ON [s].[Id] = [t0].[UserAccountsId]
LEFT JOIN [UserPermissions] AS [u] ON [s].[Id] = [u].[UserAccountModelId]
ORDER BY [s].[Id], [t0].[CustomerAccountsId], [t0].[UserAccountsId], [t0].[Id]
```

Remote server, simply doesn't include them:

```
SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[ContactEmail], [s].[ContactPhoneNumber], [s].[Created], [s].[DeletedAt], [s].[FirstActive], [s].[FirstName], [s].[InternalUser], [s].[IsDeleted], [s].[LastActive], [s].[LastName], [s].[LockId], [s].[SelectedCustomerAccounts], [s].[Title], [s].[Updated], [s].[UserRoleId]
FROM [UserAccounts] AS [s]
```

Comment: EF Core has no `WithProjection` or `Entity<>` methods. Queries are written in LINQ. Where did these come from? Are you using AutoMapper to map EF query results to DTOs? This only works up to a point. As AutoMapper docs *strongly* warn, AutoMapper is only meant for simple mappings based on conventions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you mean? The EntityTypeBuilder (builder.Entity) are literally from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders namespace. 

And again, this all works locally. The expected SQL is being created here, but not there

Comment: Probably you use my answer [WithProjection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73491471/10646316)? It is not standard technique. And actually I have created this function as answer to your question.

Comment: Probably it do not work because it detects `IsUnderDotnetTool`. Check that.

Comment: @RandyHall you didn't say this is in `OnModelBuilding`. There's no `WithProjections` method in the model builder. Model building doesn't (at least *shouldn't*) try to affect the shape of query results, it's meant to define the mappings between entities and tables. The shape of query results is the job of queries. AutoMapper has [Query Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) that include `ProjectTo` but these work at the *query* side.