# Can a model have a generated property with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Say I have a model called "Blog". I want add a property "Status" to the model. The value of that property must be retrieved from the relationship "Posts". E.g.:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .Property(b => b.Status)
        .GenerateValue(b => b.Posts.Select(...).First());
}
```

Is that possible with EF Core?

Comment: I've read this 3 times now and I still don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidG I rephrased the question. Try again.

Comment: @DarkLeafyGreen, you can't do that with pure EF Core. I have [answered similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73491471/10646316) But for such entities you have to call `ApplyCustomProjection(context)` before materialization. Also these entities will be not tracked.

Comment: Can I ask you why do you need to do that? It seems risky from a DB perspective, I feel like if you want to reference the Posts table it would be better to use a Foreign Key.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv That seems an awfully hacky way to do it. Why not just pull the value out of the DB with a `.Select(x => Status = x.Child.Whatever))`? At least that way you're not getting confused about where the property is in the database when writing to the parent table.

Comment: @DavidG, who knows ;) Sometimes OP needs something *interesting* and *generic*. For sure I'm using `Select` for such purpose.

Comment: Right now I am using automapper to augment the blog model with the status property. But it does not play nice with my custom ef core extensions. This is why I was asking, if I could reach for the value directly from the model, trick efcore into believing that is a real property. @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks going to check out your answer.