# How to set additional [Not Mapped] properties querying the database with a property in EF Core 6 resultset class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, architecture, dbcontext

When I query a table in my database using EF Core 6, I get an `IEnumerable` or a list of items, like this:

```cs
public class SqlService
{
    private IDbContextFactory<WebContext> CtxFactory { get; set; }

    public SqlService(IDbContextFactory<WebContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        CtxFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }
    
    public List<Test> WithoutMail()
    {
        using var ctx = CtxFactory.CreateDbContext();
        
        return ctx.Test.Where(p => p.EMail == null).ToList();
    }
}
```

Now my results represent instances of my class `Test` like this:

```cs
private class Test
{
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    
    // ... more properties
}
```

What I want is a (not mapped) property, querying the database with a value from one of the properties like:

```cs
private class Test
{
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    
    // ... more properties

    [NotMapped]
    public string ValueFromQuery => [CTX].SomeOtherTable.Where(p => p.Value == SomeValue);
}
```

But of course, I have no context here and no database service. Is this possible? Is this the wrong way? Should I implement another method in SQL service to handle this task?

It would be nice to "extend" the class this way with some additional properties that come from the db depending on a value in the table.

Comment: My advice: don't do this. It pollutes your entities and is confusing to anyone else who may use your code. Just make your own intermediate class and project into that instead.

Comment: If you establish a foreign key relationship between the two tables, then you can include the additional table in the query and your calculated expression from the other table will not need any additional db access.

Comment: Not a big fan of such solutions but I have created the [following approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73491471/10646316). Pros here that yo do not mix DbContext with entities. Probably it will work for you also.