# Filter some columns from IQueryable in c#

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, iqueryable

I need to remove some columns from an IQueryable that include another object using reflection (so i don't want to use anonymous type for create the new IQueryable without a columns).

I've tried this but this isn't the  right solution:

```
    string[] columnsToRemove = { "Insurance" };
    var myQuery = _dataService.GetQuery<Insurance>().Include(i => i.Partner);

    var attributes = myQuery.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var attribute in attributes)
    {
        foreach (var column in columnsToRemove)
        {
            if (attribute.Name != column)
            {
                // Remove the column from query
                var newQuery = myQuery.Where(t => t.GetType().GetProperty(column).Name != column);
                return newQuery;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot remove columns from `IQueryable`. you can apply `Select` to `IQueryable` with new projection which do not select specific column but also select others.  What you have tried has no sense.

Comment: thanks, this is what i want can you give me the code for do this?

Comment: No, it is complex task when you have Includes. `Select` should repeat Include also like `Select(inv => new Invoice { Partner = inv.Partner, ... })`. Start your question from problem which you are trying to solve.

Comment: Maybe you need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73491471/10646316) ?

Comment: Did you try to find other questions on this topic? There really are many of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try usin `Select`, but you will need to list all properties except for the excluded one:

```cs
var myQuery = _dataService.GetQuery<Insurance>()
   .Select(i => new Insurance
   {
      Partner = i.Partner,
      // ... rest of the properties except for Insurance
   });
```

Note that in case of EF and `Select` `Include` will not have effect, so you will need to explicitly set the corresponding property in query.

Other options

- Use DTOs and some tool like AutoMapper with [`ProjectTo` from queryable extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html).
- Use [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) and build the string for select dynamically (see the `.Select("new(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");` in examples)

Comment: i dont't want to specify all'the columns beacouse i need to generalize this code

Comment: @DevAB either use tool like `AutoMapper` - see the link in the answer or try avoiding such generalization.